# Problems connecting a servo to raspberry pi 5

Tags: gpio, servo, pi-5

I have recently tried to use a servo on a raspberry pi 5 using

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
from time import sleep   
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 


GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)  
p = GPIO.PWM(17, 50)     
p.start(0)               


p.ChangeDutyCycle(3)     
sleep(1)                 
p.ChangeDutyCycle(12)    
sleep(1)


p.stop()                 
GPIO.cleanup()
```

But when using this code im getting an error: Access GPIO pins without root. No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!

The error occurs at:

```
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
```

I have tried the command

```
sudo adduser pi gpio
```

I get the respond

```
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 244, 0 Dec 28 22:51 /dev/gpiomem
```

But it is still not working...

I have noticed i have 4 diffrent gpiomem files on my pi: gpiomem1, gpiomem2, gpiomem3, gpiomem4

I have also tried to reboot the whole system and image my driver again. But it still the same problem.

When i try to run the script in the terminal I get this error:

```
malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
```

When i debug it mentions that the error occurs at

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

I hope somebody can help

Comment: `RPi.GPIO` does NOT work on a Raspberry Pi 5. Switch to `gpiod`.

Comment: Did you put yourself in the gpio group?

Answer (score 0):

The Pi5 uses different hardware to implement the GPIO.  This different hardware is likely going to be used for all future Pi models.

Existing established GPIO libraries such as wiringPi, RPi.GPIO, and pigpio were written for the earlier hardware and are unlikely ever to be rewritten to support the new GPIO hardware.

I suggest you look at [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), (my) [lg](https://abyz.me.uk/lg/), or [gpiod](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/) which work on the Pi5.  They all use the current standard Linux GPIO API based on the `/dev/gpiochip` interface.

None of these libraries will be very good at driving servos as the underlying `/dev/gpiochip` interface only provides software timed pulses.

Answer (score 0):

As joan has stated none of the existing libraries will work on Pi5 (including my own pi-gpio) and the gpiochip interface only permits basic functionality.

I am working to adapt my existing I²C and SPI code which uses the kernel drivers to hopefully work on the Pi5 (I don't yet have a Pi5 and they are out of stock on all Australian authorised resellers). I have been developing PWM code using the kernel PWM sysfs overlay. This is working fine on my Pi4 under Bookworm and I expect it should work on a Pi5. I have not yet tested with a servo but plan to do so shortly.

My current code:-
(If it works on Pi5 it probably won't be in "/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0")

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""
This code provides user space access to the PWM hardware.
    The Pi has 2 independent hardware PWM channels.
    The same  PWM channel is available on multiple pins but the output is identical
    Channel 0 can be accessed on GPIO 12, 18, 40, 52
    Channel 1 can be accessed on GPIO 13, 19, 41, 45, 53
    
The kernel PWM service needs to be started before use.

To set up PWM on GPIO 18/19 
    dtoverlay=pwm-2chan in config.txt 
    sudo dtoverlay pwm-2chan on command line

To set up PWM on GPIO 12/13
    dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=12,func=4,pin2=13,func2=4
    sudo dtoverlay pwm-2chan  pin=12 func=4 pin2=13 func2=4

There is a service pwm to set up a single channel.
"""

# 2023-11-24

import sys, os, time
PWM_SYSFS = "/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0"

def kpwm_export(chan) :
    """
    Export PWM channel
    chan: 0 or 1
    NOTE a short delay is needed following kpwm_export
    """
    if not os.path.isdir(PWM_SYSFS) :
        print("Overlay not loaded")
        exit()
    if os.path.isdir(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}") :
        return  # already exported
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/export", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{chan}")

def kpwm_unexport(chan) :
    """
    Unexport PWM channel
    chan: 0 or 1
    """
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/unexport", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{chan}")

def kpwm_get_period(chan) :
    """
    chan: 0 or 1
    """
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}/period", "r") as f:
        return int(f.read())

def kpwm_enable(chan, enable) :
    """
    Enable/disable PWM on chan
    chan: 0 or 1
    enable: 0 or 1
    """
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}/enable", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{enable}")

def kpwm_set_pulse_width(chan, pulse_width) :
    """
    chan: 0 or 1
    pulse_width: The period of the PWM signal in nanoseconds
    """
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}/duty_cycle", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{pulse_width}")

def kpwm_set_duty_cycle(chan, duty_cycle) :
    """
    chan: 0 or 1
    duty_cycle: 0.0 - 1.0
    """
    pulse_width = int(kpwm_get_period(chan) * duty_cycle)
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}/duty_cycle", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{pulse_width}")

def kpwm_start(chan, period, pulse_width) :
    """
    Enable the PWM on chan, setting period and pulse_width
    chan: 0 or 1
    period: The period of the PWM signal in nanoseconds
    pulse_width: The period of the PWM signal in nanoseconds
    """
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}/period", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{period}")
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}/duty_cycle", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{pulse_width}")
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{chan}/enable", "w") as f:
        f.write("1")

def kpwm_start_f(chan, frequency, duty_cycle) :
    """
    Enable the PWM on chan, setting frequency and duty_cycle
    chan: 0 or 1
    frequency: The frequency of the PWM signal in Hz
        (used to calculate period to nearest 10nS)
    duty_cycle: 0.0 - 1.0
    """
    period = int(1000000000/frequency)
    pulse_width = int(period * duty_cycle)
    print(f"period = {period} pulse_width = {pulse_width}")
    return kpwm_start(chan, period, pulse_width)

def main():
    kpwm_export(0)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Servo frequency 50Hz period 20mSec (20,000,000nSec) pulse_width 1.5mSec (1,500,000nSec)
    kpwm_start(0, 20000000, 1500000)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```