Troubleshooting PWM via sysfs
Recently, I've discovered that I can use the sysfs to control the pwm of my raspberry pi 5. (I don't know about any libraries that are supported buy the pi-5 and can control pwm hardware.) Upon trying to test out the pwm by making an LED 50% brightness I ran into an issue where the pin wasn't outputting any value at all. I'm using pin 18 but I later swapped it to pin 12 (as pwm0 is sometimes pin 12) while troubleshooting - still no change. I also swapped around the period and duty_cycle values a few times from 10,000,000 and 5,000,000 respectively to 5000; 2500, but no change occurred. Here are the commands I used to communicate with the pwm:
cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0
echo 0 > export
cd pwm0
echo ____ > period
echo ____ > duty_cycle
echo 1 > enable

Some things to note:
I realized I hadn't setup my pwm command line properly, so I went to /boot/firmware/config.txt and added a line of setup code. Here is the full config.txt file contents. (with the pwm command added)
# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented
# /boot/firmware/overlays/README

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load initramfs files, if found
auto_initramfs=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
# Use the kernel's default instead.
disable_fw_kms_setup=1

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[cm5]
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]

When I went to /sys/kernel/debug/pwm it displayed:
pwm-0 (sysfs): requested enabled period: ___ ns duty: ___ ns polarity: normal
This probably means that the pwm is being outputted somewhere. Does anyone know what might be causing the pin 18/12 to output no value?

Have you declared the correct overlay in /boot/firmware/config.txt?

@Seamus Yes, at least I think so,   (I might’ve made an error.) I wrote dtoverlay.pwm-2chan in the “optional hardware” section of the configuration.

That doesn't look correct. You should check that; copy exactly what you have in config.txt, and add that as an edit to your question.

@Seamus I've updated the original post.

That's a much improved question. FWIW, it seems you were fairly close to getting your PWM working. I've added a note w/ a link to the kernel documentation for the PWM sysfs interface (pretty austere docs!). And most of the rest of it came from the RPi docs on the overlays under the pwm overlay. IMHO, the mindless device numbering schemes used in the kernel code is what makes this difficult.

This seems to work for me:
Load the overlay & "poke around"
$ sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt 
# add line: 'dtoverlay=pwm'
# using defaults for 'pin' & 'func' parameters: 18,2
# save & close, then re-boot
# after reboot:
#
$ ls /sys/class/pwm
pwmchip0  pwmchip2  pwmchip6

# on RPi 5 the PWM controller is pwmchip2

$ cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:25 device -> ../../../1f00098000.pwm
--w--w---- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:25 export
-r--r--r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:25 npwm
drwxrwxr-x 2 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:25 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:25 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/pwm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:25 uevent
--w--w---- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:25 unexport

Run the following commands in designated folder:
$ cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2

$ echo 2 > export

$ ls -l 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:25 device -> ../../../1f00098000.pwm
--w--w---- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:34 export
-r--r--r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:25 npwm
drwxrwxr-x 2 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:25 power
drwxrwxr-x 3 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:34 pwm2   # <== NOTE!!
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:25 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/pwm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:25 uevent
--w--w---- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:25 unexport
#
# let's have a look in 'pwm2':
#
$ ls -l pwm2
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:34 capture
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:36 duty_cycle
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:36 enable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:35 period
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:34 polarity
drwxrwxr-x 2 root gpio     0 Aug 15 00:34 power
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root gpio 16384 Aug 15 00:34 uevent

So most files in /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm2 look relevant to PWM!
Write some values to files in pwm2:
$ cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm2

$ echo 2000000 > period 

$ echo 1000000 > duty_cycle 

$ echo 1 > enable

Hopefully, you can now see a square wave w/ 50% duty cycle on GPIO 18 (header pin 12) - as shown below. Change duty_cycle & period to suit your needs.
Following is what I see on my o'scope w/ echo 2000000 > period, and echo 1000000 > duty_cycle:


NOTES:

I'm presently unsure what the difference(s) are in the dtoverlays pwm and pwm-2chan. I'll try to scope that out when I've got more time - or maybe you already know? In any case, hopefully this gets you on your way.

The PWM controller for the RPi 5 is not pwmchip0 - it's pwmchip2

The kernel documentation for the PWM device

See this other answer for a how-to on using both hardware PWM channels.



I see, I’ll have a look at that a bit later and let you know if it works. What are the pins for pwmchip2? I know for pwmchip0 that pwm0 = gpio18/12 and so on but what is are the pins that pwmchip2 controls?

@MatthewMoller: Uh, no... the pin for pwmchip2 is GPIO 18, which is physically located at pin #12 on the board. Where did you get your information for what you were trying to do?

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/145068/8697 for details of the overlays and channels which would be pwm0 & pwm1 and also the alternative pin allocation.
